# Need help creating add rows function with MySQL dependent dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, forms, dynamic, dropdown

[Single Hardware Modification](https://codepen.io/delnoth/pen/mdMLQor)

[Mulitple Hardware Modifications](https://replit.com/@BJBRITT82/MultiLine-Dropdown#ajaxData.php)

I am trying to set up an equipment log using MySQL, PHP, and JavaScript. I have been trying to teach myself over the past 3 months. A lot of what I have is from code I have found here or on other forums.

I have a page dedicated to inputting hardware changes on our equipment. The Subsystem and Component dropdowns are set to pull the subsystem list from the database, and the component list is populated based off subsystem selection. I have not gotten that far into JavaScript, so I do not fully understand some of what this code means.

I have the page set up to input one modification, then after submitting, there is a link to return to the page to add another modification. This option is working as expected. My dropdowns work and my data is input into my database as expected.

I am trying to set up a page so that if there are multiple modifications, they can be added on one page. All of my text input fields on the form work as expected. I am able to create the first dropdown for the subsystem and populate it with my table data, but the component dropdown does not populate. I have been following this tutorial from [webslesson.com](https://www.webslesson.info/2019/09/add-or-remove-dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-with-php-ajax.html#comment-form). In it he uses 1 table. I have been trying to adapt it for the 2 tables that I am using, but I am getting some of the functions wrong.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction of where I can learn where my code is going off track? I am trying to learn, but at this point I am not exactly sure how to phrase what I am looking for.

I appreciate you taking a look at this. Please do not be too harsh on my poor code. I am working to make it better as I learn.

Above are links to my CodePen.io and repl.it for the 2 versions of my page. I had to

This is my table setup:

lu_subsystem
|id|subsystem_name|
|--|--------------|

lu_component
|component_id|subsystem_id|component_name|
|------------|------------|--------------|

```
<?php

//index.php

include('database_connection.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Remove Dynamic Dependent Select Box using Ajax jQuery with PHP</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
      <h3 align="center">Add Remove Dynamic Dependent Select Box using Ajax jQuery with PHP</h3>
      <br />
      <h4 align="center">Enter Item Details</h4>
      <br />
      <form method="post" id="insert_form">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <span id="error"></span>
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Enter Item Name</th>
                <th>Subsystem</th>
                <th>Component</th>
                <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
          <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      var count = 0;

      $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="subsystem_id[]" class="form-control subsystem_id" data-subsystem_id="'+count+'"><option value="">Select Subsystem</option><?php echo fill_select_box($connect, "0"); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_component_id[]" class="form-control item_component_id" id="item_component_id'+count+'"><option value="">Select Component</option></select></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });

      $(document).on('change', '.subsystem_id', function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var component_id = $(this).data('component_id');
        $.ajax({
          url:"fill_sub_category.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{subsystem_id:subsystem_id},
          success:function(data)
          {
            var html = '<option value="">Select Component</option>';
            html += data;
            $('#item_component_id'+component_id).html(html);
          }
        })
      });

      $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var error = '';
        $('.item_name').each(function(){
          var count = 1;
          if($(this).val() == '')
          {
            error += '<p>Enter Item name at '+count+' Row</p>';
            return false;
          }
          count = count + 1;
        });

        $('.item_category').each(function(){
          var count = 1;

          if($(this).val() == '')
          {
            error += '<p>Select Item Category at '+count+' row</p>';
            return false;
          }

          count = count + 1;

        });

        $('.item_component_id').each(function(){

          var count = 1;

          if($(this).val() == '')
          {
            error += '<p>Select Item Sub category '+count+' Row</p> ';
            return false;
          }

          count = count + 1;

        });

        var form_data = $(this).serialize();

        if(error == '')
        {
          $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(data)
            {
              if(data == 'ok')
              {
                $('#item_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
                $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
              }
            }
          });
        }
        else
        {
          $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
        }

      });
      
    });
</script>
```

```
<?php

//database_connection.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bunker_logs;", "root", "");

function fill_select_box($connect, $id)
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM lu_subsystem
  ";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

 $statement->execute();

 $result = $statement->fetchAll();

 $output = '';

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["subsystem_name"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}

function fill_component_box($connect, $component_id)
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM lu_component
  WHERE component_id ='".$id."'
  ";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

 $statement->execute();

 $result = $statement->fetchAll();

 $output = '';

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["component_id"].'">'.$row["component_name"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}

?>
```

```
<?php

//fill_component.php

include('database_connection.php');


echo fill_component_box($connect, $_POST["subsystem_id"]);
?>
```

Comment: It was pointed out to me that one of the PHP files was missing. I updated the Multiple Input link to a repl.it that has the PHP file code included.

Comment: I have tried a different approach following a different tutorial. I updated my code and my replit.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into your code, and to be honest, I haven't done much in jQuery. However, I still want to give you an example on how you can implement the information on your page from my experience:

You can either pull the information directly from the database with PHP without using JavaScript. If you use PDO for this, you get a muldimension array.

You can then "walk" through the array with a foreach loop

```
$select ='<select id='yourChoice'>';
foreach($array as $component){
    $name = component['name'];
    $select.="<option value='$name'> $name </option>;
};
$select.='</select>';
```

In this case the $array is the full printout from the database, and goes through each row ( $component)

It then selects the column name, and fills it in.

If you want to do the same thing with JavaScript, you can do it with JSON, walking through that array.
Unfortunately, I don't have an example ready for that one at the moment.